# One rewrite rule or multiple ones in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have a main domain, a couple of addon domains and recently went https. This is working ok for me but i would like your opinion:

```
## All http requests to the relative https url
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 [OR]
## redirect the other domains and the non www main main domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain3.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain3.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain2.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain2.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^maindomain.com
## this stuff is for SSL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
## i send them all to the https main domain
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.maindomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This is better approach to have a rewrite rule for each condition?

Comment: Might be better on https://www.serverfault.com or https://www.superuser.com sister sites

Comment: Well you are right, i will post it there

Comment: Cross-site post: this question already has an answer here... http://serverfault.com/questions/843338/one-rewrite-rule-or-multiple-ones-in-htaccess